# Using JQuery UI to convert radio buttons into slider elements

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-ui, user-interface, radio-button

I have a form which is rendered with radio buttons like so:

```
<h2>How long is your hair?</h2>
<input type="radio" name="71" value="98">Short 
<input type="radio" name="71" value="99">Medium 
<input type="radio" name="71" value="100">Long
```

There are about 15 questions like this, and I would like to have the whole form rendered with sliders, using JQuery (Jquery UI seems like the most likely candidate).

I have found a few plugins for converting select boxes to sliders (e.g. [selectToUISlider](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/update_jquery_ui_slider_from_a_select_element_now_with_aria_support//)) but none for radio buttons.

I'm sure it is possible to roll my own somehow using the standard UI Slider, but I don't really know where to start. Has anyone already made a plug in to achieve this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here's the basic structure of one option, I'm not sure how your questions differ (do they all have 3 options?) so the styling would vary, just trying to demonstrate the concept.

I'm not sure what each question is contained in, so I put your content in a `<div class="question">`, then gave the inputs labels (degrades a bit better for non-JS users), like this overall:

```
<div class="question">
  <h2>How long is your hair?</h2>
  <label><input type="radio" name="71" value="98">Short</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="71" value="99">Medium</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="71" value="100">Long</label>
</div>
```

Then a bit of script to transform it into a slider, like this:

```
$(".question").each(function() {
    var radios = $(this).find(":radio").hide();
    $("<div></div>").slider({
      min: parseInt(radios.first().val(), 10),
      max: parseInt(radios.last().val(), 10),
      slide: function(event, ui) {
        radios.filter("[value=" + ui.value + "]").click();
      }
    }).appendTo(this);
});
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/KTvCV/)

Comment: this is one of the best answers I've ever seen on SO. Please can we have more Nick Cravers?

Comment: That's fantastic and works beautifully.

In other news: jsfiddle is awesome