# Jquery slider with radio buttons

Tags: jquery, slider

I've been reading this [1]: [Using JQuery UI to convert radio buttons into slider elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3530652/using-jquery-ui-to-convert-radio-buttons-into-slider-elements)

and now have a slider that slides using radio buttons. I'm having trouble trying to set the default value of the slider. I have a hidden field on the page that contains the default value as a number and I want the radio button with that id to be checked and have the slider represent this. All i can think of doing is using javascript to check that radio button. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ELEMENT.prop("checked", true)` under jQuery 1.6 or `ELEMENT.attr('checked','checked')` for anything under jQuery 1.6 to check the radio button, and for the slider you can use `SLIDER_ELEMENT.value(MY_VALUE)` to set the value of it.