# Which li tag is clicked after form is submitted?

Tags: php, forms

```
<form method="post" action="" id="myForm">
<ul>
    <li>Male</li>
    <li>Female</li>
</ul>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" />

</form>
```

After the form is submitted .How can i know which li tag is clicked and i want to post that to php

Comment: <li> tags are not form elements.

Comment: You should use radio button for such selections

Answer (score 3, accepted):

give ids and classes to the li tags to register the click event, on that click event update a hidden field with the id, index, or text of the li so that it will be available on post. If you are unable to give unique id's or text values you can just use the index() of the li.

```
<form method="post" action="" id="myForm">
<ul>
   <li id='male' class="sex">Male</li>
   <li id='female' class="sex">Female</li>
</ul>
<input type="hidden" id="selectedsex" />                    
<input type="submit" name="submit" />

</form>

$('.sex').click(function () {
    var val = $(this).attr('id');
    $('#selectedsex').val(val);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Like **Amritpal Singh** suggested:

```
<form method="post" action="" id="myForm">
   <select name="gender">
      <option value="Male">Male</option>
      <option value="Female">Female</option>
   </select>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" /> 
</form>
```

Comment: Ah, then refer to this helpful post:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3530652/using-jquery-ui-to-convert-radio-buttons-into-slider-elements

Answer (score 2):

Plain `<li>` elements are not clickable and wont provide any data to your POST variable. You can use radio buttons for this.

Comment: I am using a jquery slider and it does not has Radio button option.So any valuable suggestion.if i get the li index then that would be great...

Comment: Why are you using a slider for a gender selection ? You have two options, either male of female. You don't need a slider, use radio buttons or select elements

Comment: actually this is not for gender i have just given you an example....it will be image .

Answer (score 1):

`index()` is zero based

```
$('#myForm li').click(function(){

        alert( $(this).index()) ;
         /* or */
        alert( $(this).text());


})
```

You could also toggle a Class on each click.... really not clear what you are asking to do

Comment: I want to know which li tag the user has clicked after the user submits the form.