# JQuery Slider Radio Button Not Appearing

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I've been trying to follow the example here: [Using JQuery UI to convert radio buttons into slider elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3530652/using-jquery-ui-to-convert-radio-buttons-into-slider-elements)

I tried to recreate the sample, but it doesn't seem to work for me. All I see are radio buttons.

Here's my code:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title> Test </title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

$(".question").each(function() {
    var radios = $(this).find(":radio").hide();
    $("<div></div>").slider({
      min: parseInt(radios.first().val(), 10),
      max: parseInt(radios.last().val(), 10),
      slide: function(event, ui) {
        radios.filter("[value=" + ui.value + "]").click();
      }
    }).appendTo(this);
});
    </script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="question">
  <h2>How long is your hair?</h2>
  <label><input type="radio" name="71" value="98">Short</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="71" value="99">Medium</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="71" value="100">Long</label>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to have a reference to the jQuery UI library.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few problems:

### Wrong selector

Your selector should be `$('#question')` because `question` is the ID of the `div`, not the class. `$('.question')` is for selecting elements in the `question` class. You either change the selector or you change the element to `<div class="question">`.

### No reference to jQuery UI

The `.slider` method is not available in 'vanilla' jQuery, you have to reference jQuery UI

### Wrong "place" for JS code

The JS code is executing before the elements are redenred. You should embed your existing code inside a `$(document).ready` call. Here more [here](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).

After all changes, your code should be like this:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js'></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css"/>

  <style type='text/css'>
    label { display: block; float: left; text-align: center; width: 33%; }
    .question > div { clear: left; }

  </style>


<script type='text/javascript'>
$(function(){
$(".question").each(function() {
    var radios = $(this).find(":radio").hide();
    $("<div></div>").slider({
      min: parseInt(radios.first().val(), 10),
      max: parseInt(radios.last().val(), 10),
      slide: function(event, ui) {
        radios.filter("[value=" + ui.value + "]").click();
      }
    }).appendTo(this);
});

$("button").click(function() {
    alert($(":radio[name=71]:checked").val());
});

});

</script>


</head>
<body>
  <div class="question">
    <h2>How long is your hair?</h2>
    <label><input type="radio" name="71" value="98">Short</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="71" value="99">Medium</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="71" value="100">Long</label>
</div>

</body>


</html>

​
```